# How to get arrays in android arrays.xml according value

Tags: android

In android arrays.xml, I can define arrays like below,

```
<string-array name="feed_icons">

    <item value="0">@drawable/latest</item>

    <item value="1">@drawable/video</item>

    <item value="2">@drawable/world</item>

    <item value="3">@drawable/sports</item>

    <item value="4">@drawable/arts</item>

    <item value="5">@drawable/dining</item>

</string-array>
```

I wonder how to get the drawable according the value? Is three any function? I just kown that,

```
String[] iconArrays = getResource().getStringArrays(R.arrays.feed_icons);
```

but it's not my desired.

Comment: Next time post your question on the right site.

Comment: you have given value as 0 to n so you can get appropriate drawable from String[] as position wise which indirectly value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could save the drawable names in an array like:

```
<string-array name="feed_icons">
    <item value="0">latest</item>
    <item value="1">video</item>
</string-array>
```

Then fetch the drawable:

```
String[] iconArrays = getResources().getStringArray(R.arrays.feed_icons);

// Get specific drawable resource id
int drawableResId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(iconArrays[0], "drawable", getPackageName());

// Fetch drawable by resource id
Drawable yourDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(drawableResId);

// Use drawable
imageView.setDrawable(yourDrawable);
```